# In Javascript, how do I tell array.filter() to duplicate element objects in the new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So simplified code.

```js
var a = [
    { name: "first", num: 1 },
    { name: "first", num: 2 },
    { name: "first", num: 3 },
    { name: "first", num: 4 },
    { name: "first", num: 5 },
    { name: "first", num: 6 },
    { name: "first", num: 7 },
    { name: "first", num: 8 },
    { name: "first", num: 9 }
];

var b = a.filter(function(el) {
    return el.num % 2 == 0;
});

console.log("a1", a); // [1, 20, 3, 40, 5, 60, 7, 80, 9]
console.log("b1", b); // [20, 40, 60, 80]

for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i].num = b[i].num * 10;
}

console.log("a2", a); // [1, 20, 3, 40, 5, 60, 7, 80, 9]
console.log("b2", b); // [20, 40, 60, 80]
```

My new understanding is the array element contains a reference to an object, not the object.  What are some ways to get those objects duplicated?

1. Filter, then build new objects from the filtered array and put the new things in a new array?
2. Use some method I'm not currently familiar with?
3. Redesign the code to stop using objects in an array?

Also, what's up with console.log() showing the variables have changed when placed before the for loop?

Comment: The browser console shows the variables in their current state, not the state they were in when they were logged.  If you `console.log('a1',JSON.stringify(a));` you should see a difference.

Comment: Use `map`, not `filter`, to create new objects (copies) in a new array.

Comment: Like `const c = b.map(({name, num}) => ({name, num: num*10}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to duplicate the objects inside the array, you should use the `map` function.

```
var b = a.filter(val => val.num %2 === 0).map(val => Object.assign({}, val, { num: val.num * 10}));
```

The map function will return a new array with the value returned from the function.  In this example, we are creating a new object `Object.assign({})` and duplicating the existing object while changing the `num` field.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Writing `name: val.name` in the object literal is probably easier than the `Object.assign` though :-)

Comment: This only works for objects 1 deep, if any of the properties are objects then you will need to deep clone.

Comment: @Bergi, yes but if you add more properties to the objects, you won't need to worry about it this way. Also I updated wording. Thank you

Comment: @Adrian Brand, that is correct, however with the use case presented, it did not seem necessary.

Comment: @AdrianBrand It's fine because only the `num` property on the first level changes in the new object.

Comment: @AdrianBrand. Thank you for mentioning 'deep clone.'  Its good to know what to look out for and have a name for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clone objects you will need a clone function, I use this function

```
const clone = obj =>
  Array.isArray(obj)
    ? obj.map(item => clone(item))
    : obj instanceof Date
    ? new Date(obj.getTime())
    : obj && typeof obj === 'object'
    ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((o, prop) => {
        o[prop] = clone(obj[prop]);
        return o;
      }, {})
    : obj;
```

You can then clone the array with

```
let c = clone(b);
```

Which will be a new array where each object is a new clone.

```js
var a = [{name: 'first', num:1}, {name:'first', num: 2}, {name:'first', num: 3}, 
   {name:'first', num: 4}, {name:'first', num: 5}, {name:'first', num: 6}, {name:'first', num: 7}, 
   {name:'first', num: 8}, {name:'first', num: 9}];

var b = a.filter(function(el){return el.num%2==0 });
   
 const clone = obj =>
    Array.isArray(obj)
      ? obj.map(item => clone(item))
      : obj instanceof Date
      ? new Date(obj.getTime())
      : obj && typeof obj === 'object'
      ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((o, prop) => {
          o[prop] = clone(obj[prop]);
          return o;
        }, {})
      : obj;

 let c = clone(b);
 
 console.log(b[0] === c[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, elements of Array `a` **are all pointers**. so you need to use `Object.assign` (as many says)

and other solution with array reduce usage (see Adrian Brand comment)

```js
var a = [ { name: 'first', num: 1 } 
        , { name: 'first', num: 2 } 
        , { name: 'first', num: 3 } 
        , { name: 'first', num: 4 } 
        , { name: 'first', num: 5 } 
        , { name: 'first', num: 6 } 
        , { name: 'first', num: 7 } 
        , { name: 'first', num: 8 } 
        , { name: 'first', num: 9 } 
        ] 

var b = a.filter(el=>!(el.num%2)).map(el=>Object.assign({},el))

// other solution with reduce 

var c = a.reduce((acc,cur)=>{
  if (!(cur.num%2) )acc.push(Object.assign({},cur))
  return acc
}, [])

ConsoleArrayNamNum('var a -1-',a)  // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ConsoleArrayNamNum('var b -1-',b)  // [2, 4, 6, 8]
ConsoleArrayNamNum('var c -1-',c)  // [2, 4, 6, 8]

for(let elm of b)
  { elm.num *= 10 }

ConsoleArrayNamNum('var a -2-',a)  // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ConsoleArrayNamNum('var b -2-',b)  // [20, 40, 60, 80]


function ConsoleArrayNamNum(title,arr) {
  console.log(title)
  for(let elm of arr)
    { console.log(`{ name: '${elm.name}', num: ${elm.num} }`) }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: This is not an answer to how to not have the same reference in the final array.

Comment: @AdrianBrand ->  my bad (or poor english; no more important after Brexit)

Comment: A filter followed by a map is best done with a reduce as it can be done in a single iteration, if item meets condition add new object to results.

Comment: @AdrianBrand, that's right; I added this one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using some ES6 syntax:

```js
var a = [{name: 'first', num:1}, {name:'first', num: 2}, {name:'first', num: 3}, 
{name:'first', num: 4}, {name:'first', num: 5}, {name:'first', num: 6}, {name:'first', num: 7}, 
{name:'first', num: 8}, {name:'first', num: 9}];

const b = a
.filter(el => {
    if (el.num % 2 === 0) {
        return {
            ...el
        }
    }
})
.map(newEl => newEl.num * 10);

console.log('a', a);  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
console.log('b', b);
```

1. .filter() iterates the "a" array and returns only elements with
   "num" property that reaches the condition. This is a cloned array.
2. `return { ...el }` returns a cloned object thanks to spread
   operator.
3. .map() creates a new array and returns each "el.num" value *
   10

Here some info about .map() .filter() and spread operator:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

I found this very interesting site that lists all Javascript functions with their descriptions and shows if is mutable or not, this helps a lot:
https://doesitmutate.xyz/

Comment: My fault. Links now point to English documentation. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new array with the final values you can use reduce to do it all in one go, reduce starts with an accumulator of an empty array and each iteration if it meets the condition it adds a clone with the spread operator overriding the num time 10.

```js
var a = [{name: 'first', num:1}, {name:'first', num: 2}, {name:'first', num: 3}, 
   {name:'first', num: 4}, {name:'first', num: 5}, {name:'first', num: 6}, {name:'first', num: 7}, 
   {name:'first', num: 8}, {name:'first', num: 9}];

const evensTimes10 = array => array.reduce((results, item) => {
  if (item.num % 2 === 0) {
    results.push({ ...item, num: item.num * 10 });
  }
  return results;
}, []);


var b = evensTimes10(a);

console.log('a1',a); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
console.log('b1',b); // [20, 40, 60, 80]
```